# How to add title on each plot in Venn diagram R

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am using R `draw.pairwise.venn` to draw venn diagrams. I want to add many venn diagram in one plot and to add different title to each one of them. 
Here is my code.

```
library(VennDiagram)
library(gridExtra)
g = draw.pairwise.venn(88, 3852, 86, category = c('A', 'B'), lty = rep("blank",2), fill = c("red", " navyblue"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(0,0), cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2,  euler.d=TRUE,  scaled=TRUE, ind = FALSE))
g1 = draw.pairwise.venn(98, 3812, 56, category = c('A', 'B'), lty = rep("blank",2), fill = c("red", " navyblue"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(0,0), cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2,  euler.d=TRUE,  scaled=TRUE, ind = FALSE))
grid.arrange(gTree(children=g),gTree(children=g1), top=c("Central Asia","Africa"))
```

I want something like this.
[image]

But it is giving me only one title CentralAsia on the top. 
Can any one help me in this matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `plot_grid` from `cowplot` to add individual labels:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(gTree(children = g), gTree(children = g1), 
                   labels = c("Central Asia","Africa"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `VennDiagram` package already has an argument for adding a title. When you plot the diagram using `draw.pairwise.venn()`, just include `main = "Central Asia"` as an argument. In your case, it will look like this:

```
g = draw.pairwise.venn(88, 3852, 86, category = c('A', 'B'), lty = rep("blank",2), main = "Central Asia", fill = c("red", " navyblue"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(0,0), cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2,  euler.d=TRUE,  scaled=TRUE, ind = FALSE))
```